# Llink Winmm.lib to Qt creator

Tags: qt, linker, mingw, winmm

Im having problems linking Winmm.lib to Qt creator, when I try to link it the library file dialog box turns red and next button is disabled.

Im using Microsoft SDKs Winmm.lib that comes with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, qtcreator5 and mingw.

Help please.

Comment: add "LIBS += -lwinmm" to the .pro file to link mingw`s winmm to qt creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking against libraries from the Microsoft Windows SDK, you need to be sure to use the Visual C++ 2010 or Visual C++ 2012 compiler and not the MinGW compiler. Visual C++ and MinGW create different and incompatible binaries and can't be linked interchangeably. If there is a library you want to use with MinGW, make sure to build it from source against MinGW. The same goes for Visual C++ 2010 and Visual C++ 2012.